# What should I expect from a 2nd phone interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, follow-up, hiring, phone

I applied for a job abroad, got a first 1 hour phone interview. A week later they called me to schedule a 2nd 30 minute interview with another person.

What does this mean? The first interview was with an executive manager, the second one is with a team manager.

Comment: "What should I expect?" Why not ask them, not us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the first executive liked your personality but he/she is not sure if your skills are up to par for the job you are interviewing for. Hence the team manager, who knows the "in"s and "out"s of the day to day requirements of this job needs to talk to you. It is not unusual to go through more than one phone interview, especially if you are not in the same locality with the company you applied to. Don't be surprised if you are asked to get on a conference call with the people who you will potentially be working with. The hiring buck doesn't stop at the executive level.

Answer (score 4):

It can vastly depend on the company. In the situation you have specifically described it appears that the first interview is more of a general/character interview to gauge your interest, manner, experience and let you ask any questions at a high level.

A team-manager lead interview would typically be more focused on your actual work, it is likely they will want to know about your experience in your field, some described projects you have worked on, what systems/processes you are familiar with e.t.c.